# Boolean expressions: function not returning expected output

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic

Question:

Write a function should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on) which returns True if the battery level is less than 4.8 except when the time_on is less than 60, in which case the function returns True only if the battery level is less than 4.7.  In all other situations the function returns False.

```
def should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on):
    if battery_level < 4.8:
        if time_on < 60:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        if battery_level < 4.7:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Testings:

`should_shutdown(4.69, 50)` *Evaluates to:* `'False'`. **Should return *`"True"`***

`should_shutdown(5, 10)` *Evaluates to:* `False`

`should_shutdown(4.74, 90)` *Evaluates to:* `True`

`should_shutdown(4.74, 50)` *Evaluates to:* `False`

`should_shutdown(4.7, 50)` *Evaluates to:* `False`

`should_shutdown(4.75, 60)` *Evaluates to:* `True`

`should_shutdown(4.75, 59)` *Evaluates to:* `False`

*The first test is not returning the expected output by the quiz server. i don't understand the question very much so that's why I've copy pasted it.*

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

1. When `battery_level < 4.7`, the function should always return True.
2. When `battery_level < 4.8` and `time_on` is *not* less than 60, the function should also return True.

Putting these two together yields:

```
def should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on):
    return (battery_level < 4.7) or (battery_level < 4.8 and time_on >= 60)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def should_shutdown(battery_level, time_on):
    if battery_level < 4.8:
        return (time_on >= 60) or (time_on < 60 and battery_level < 4.7)
    return False
```

This should be the function for the above question